# Google Contextual Gadget with delegation

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I'm willing to developp a contextual gadget inside a Google Apps GMail.
I have made somes tests on the gadget but I have still some questions about the identities involved.

I need some informations about the current email (done with the extractors) and some informations regarding the current user logged BUT I also need informations about the user reading the email and the current mailbox accessed.

ie. If UserB has a delegation on UserA, when UserB opens a mail in UserA mailbox I need to know both identities (UserA and UserB).

How could I get that informations ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like it can't be done with a contextual gadget as this information is not provided with the standard extractors available to you.

I would guess the best way to approach this would be to use a Chrome Extension.  With a Chrome extension you can access the Gmail DOM and perform some fairly complex actions.  You might be able to determine from the Gmail DOM that a user is viewing a delegated mailbox...  But then again it might not be possible.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion. Possible actions inside a Gadget are very limited.I've done some tests and the Chrome Extension is able to retrieve this kind of informations, but the execution of the extension is not garanteed.